# MySQL 5.7: Problems with DATETIME = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

since I upgraded my MySQL-Database to 5.7, I have problems when I try to set a datetime column to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`:

```
UPDATE users
SET updateTime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
WHERE id = 123;

// #1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'updateTime ' at row 1
```

If I run the Query with `UPDATE IGNORE [...]`, it works fine.

The SQL-Mode `NO_ZERO_DATE` is not set. Is there any setting to fix this?

I realy would hate to add `IGNORE` to every query in the application.

Comment: Why would you want to do such thing? if you need an empty date - make the field nullable and use `NULL` as the value

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The field can already be set to NULL. Changing it would cause some side effects (even more bugs), that´s why I need to find a hotfix. After it is working again, I´ll have to find a "best practice solution".

Comment: With "It is already set to NULL" I mean, that NULL can be set. I am not sure, if this will not cause many new problems. I am checking this right now.

Comment: Just for the record, `NO_ZERO_DATE` [has been deprecated](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-deprecations)

Comment: Do you have the `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` or `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` modes enabled?

Comment: _What_ `DATETIME` column? What does it look like? Where is your [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? FFS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when updating form Ubuntu 14.04 repo mysql 5.5.6? to mysql 5.7.9

I am using a perl script to do several load data infile where the date is sometimes `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. I also get err 1292 in DBO tracewhich was solved by removing `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` from sql mode in optionsfile.